# Is there a (real) number which gives a rational number both when multiplied by $\pi$ and when multiplied by $e$?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

Besides $0$ of course. What about addition and exponentiation? I would think there's no such number, but I'm not sure if I could prove it.

Comment: You mean like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_identity

Comment: Are you asking whether $e/\pi$ is rational?

Comment: Allowing exponentiation changes things, but if you just stick to +,-,x,and division this question is still open. To be more precise, it is not known whether $\pi$ and $e$ are algebraically independent or not. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is open whether there is such number. The reason is that we do not know whether $e/\pi$ is rational, but this is *equivalent* to your question (for a recent accessible reference, see for example [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/e.html) and the links provided there):

Note that if $xe$ and $x\pi$ are rational, then so is their quotient, $e/\pi$. Conversely, if $e/\pi$ is rational, then take $x=1/\pi$ and note that $xe$ and $x\pi$ are rational.

Answer (score 4):

However, it is known that at least one of
$e+\pi$ and $e \pi$ is not only irrational
but transcendental.
We just don't know which one.
Of course,
everybody believes that both are.

Proof: Consider $x^2 - (e +\pi) x + e \pi$.

Comment: Similarly, at least one of $\;\mathrm e+1/\pi$ and $\mathrm e/\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: The four basic operations are frequently considered to be $+$, $-$, $\times$, and $\div$.  This gives the nice statement that all but at most one of $e+\pi$, $e-\pi$, $e\pi$, and $e/\pi$ are transcendental.  If you consider exponentiation another basic operation, you can add $e^\pi$ to that statement, because that's known to be transcendental!

Answer (score 3):

It is not known, since it is not known if $\pi/e$ is rational or not: if $a\pi$ and $ae$ were rational, then so would be $\pi/e$.